# How to Zip an Azure Website

Tags: azure, ftp, zip, backup, azure-web-app-service

I have a WordPress installation on an Azure Website (not a WebRole). I have FTP access to the site but it literally can take like an hour, which is insane because if I could just ZIP the thousands of files on the site (due to all the plugins, etc) it might take 5 seconds to run the zip. Downloading that then would be far more reliable, as its just 1 file, not 10,000 that could get messed in transfer. Traditional hosters allow you to get on their control panel and zip folders, for instance, but FTP doesn't allow this.

So can I do this on an Azure website, any way, shape or how??? I've looked a bit into SFTP which seems to have some such capabilities but it doesn't seem to be implemented in Azure websites. What can I do, this whole work flow is despisable, I can't live with it, it discourages backups. This encourages one to go to a traditional shared host but I would rather not if possible.

Comment: The winSCP is working for this situation?

Comment: I don't know about winSCP (http://winscp.net/eng/index.php). I would love for that to work, but I guess I'm skeptical it could work with a plain Azure website, but if you know how, please advise! Thanks

Comment: I have no experience with websites but with azure VM you can use winSCP to connect to the host and select files you want and then with right click -> Custom Commands you make the tarball.

Comment: There's a ZIP SCM endpoint that will get you this. For instance visit https://user:pass@mysitename.scm.azurwebsites.net/zip/foo/bar-under-wwwroot where user and pass are your publishing credentials
This should produce a zip of everything under wwwroot/foo/bar

Comment: Hi Pranav, I tried that and I got the message "this webpage is not available." Are you sure about the link? This is what I tried: https://myusername:mypassword@mycoolsitename.scm.azurwebsites.net/zip/wp-admin/ The 'username' for the pubprofile starts with a dollar sign, but I tried with/without that.

Comment: My bad, I should have checked first. The url should look like this https://myusername:mypassword@mycoolsitename.scm.azurwebsites.net/zip/site/wwwroot/wp-admin/

Comment: Neither Chrome nor IE like this address. IE says: "[Prompt with title: Address Bar] Windows cannot find :thepasswordyouentered. Check the spelling and try again." Let me give a full sample url. If your site was called 'catsarecool', here's the url I'm using then:

https://$catsarecool:jCkad9aSewjr9flksX9dru2pk09xUijcv90wejf9w230d9euF9jw90eFKefd@catsarecool.scm.azurwebsites.net/zip/site/wwwroot/wp-admin/
The browsers do not like that 'url', and frankly it looks wrong to me too.

Comment: Odd, Chrome does work work for me with a similar url. Could you try without specifying the credentials in the url? In essence, try https://catsarecool.scm.azurewebsites.net/zip/site/wwwroot/wp-admin/ When your browser prompts you for credentials, $catsarecool would be the username and the portion following the colon would be the password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Kudu Console. To access it, simply go to {yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net. 
You will then be prompted for your login credentials for your Microsoft Azure Account. Once logged in, click on 'Debug Console' at the top of the web page.

Within the UI, Next to each file and folder, there is a Down Arrow icon that lets you download the item.

For files, it directly downloads the file by navigating to it.

For directories, it downloads a zip file containing the full content of the folder.

Detailed instructions can be found here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. After "click on 'Debug Console' at the top of the web page" please add something like "and select one of the console options (PowerShell or CMD)." Really glad they implemented this. I will note though that the first time I tried just now I got a lot of spinning waiting for a download and it doing nothing. But later (in separate download tries) they all downloaded in a jiff.

Comment: The download is actually slow with indeterminate size as it does not send the `Content-length` header with the file.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a screeshot of kudu-console. 
[image: kudu-console]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be the Kudu API, you can accomplish a lot of stuff with it such as downloading a folder from the app service as ZIP as well as automating this using a script. Use the following link within a web browser for example:

If logged in to kudu from the browser just use:

```
https://{{your-site}}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/{{folder-path}}
```

If using a script or command line pass your credentials as follows:

```
https://user:pass@{{your-site}}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/{{folder-path}}
```

Where `user` and `pass` can be obtained by going to your app service in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and clicking *Get Publish Profile* in the Overview tab. See the [Deployment Credetials documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) for more details.

[image: Azure portal overview tab]

**Note:** The folder path starts from `D:\home`.

For more information consult the kudu [Rest API documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip).